# xls2csv getting an error while running xls2csv file1.xls > file1.csv

Tags: linux

```
Can't locate Locale/Recode.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.10.0 /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 .) at /usr/local/bin/xls2csv line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/bin/xls2csv line 9.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no access to the Module Locale/Recode.pm.
you need to install xls2csv correcly.
it's recommended to use CPAN for installing that's sometimes easier 
compared to the make installation as it does not always care for dependencies.

Just check with a perl program like the one below.
Fix any error before you run the whole xls2csv.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use 5.006;

use Getopt::Std;
use Locale::Recode;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::FmtUnicode;
use Text::CSV_XS;
```

Comment: in case the missing modules are (installed) on the machine, you can correct by providing the path by adding a line like      use lib '................';